# GRUB rescue and out of memory - killing process occurs when I start my laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

Using USB booting, I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64 bit on my LENEVO Ideapad G50 - 70 dual boot with windows 8.1
- In order to overcome **Ubi partman error 10 ( I think its RAID isssue)** by using -> Try Ubuntu -> clicked on install Ubuntu icon -> pressed F6 when "Choose your language" window appeared and I skipped that error. Then I made 3 partitions for \ ,\home and swape using "Something else option in installation".
It worked fine. Ububtu boot loader was giving me both options to use either ubuntu OS or windows 8.1 OS.

-Now in win 8.1, I opened **"Disk management"** and found that there was about 128 GB free space and 42 GB un-located space. I decided to delete my D:/ partition and then with the newly increased free space, I will create a new partition.

But after shrinking D:\ to 100mb and then clicking on delete 'X' icon, the laptop **hanged** and I pressed power button for long time and then the laptop switched off.

On start up again, I found GRUB RESCUE COMMANDS and it told **No such partition**.

Then again I boot up using USB and on selecting "Try Ubuntu", It gave me a long list of **Out of Memory ---- Killing process** list.

And even when I inserted my old win xp disk for formatting the HDD, it was a **Black screen** after the line -> Press any key to boot from cd...

What has happened with my laptop? Is it any RAM hardware or software problem? How to fix it?
Is all the data on my HDD lost!!!!

Comment: Do not trust Windows to show LInux partitions. And editing partition with Linux installed may delete the Linux partition from partition table. Is system UEFI or BIOS? Post this above from live installer: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: You mentioned "that error" after you pressed F6 when installing Ubuntu, but didn't specify what the error was. Given that earlier error where I wouldn't expect one and the fact that your boot of the Ubuntu installation/rescue image is now failing, I suspect you may be running into a hardware problem. It might be wise to physically move the hard disk to another computer and use it to back up any important data. Beyond that, diagnosing and fixing the problem might require a lot of expertise and back-and-forth exchanges, and I don't think this forum is the best place for that.

Comment: @ oldfred . The system is UEFI

Comment: Even now when I insert windows installation CD, it get stuck at starting windows.

Comment: And once when I started the laptop, quick continuous CPU beep began without any display.